# What Named Entity Recognition tools support Ukrainian language?

Tags: resource-request, software

[Named-entity recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) (NER) (also known as entity identification, entity chunking and entity extraction) is a subtask of information extraction that seeks to locate and classify named entities in text into pre-defined categories such as the names of persons, organizations, locations, expressions of times, quantities, monetary values, percentages, etc.

Tools that I used used ([DBpedia Spotlight](http://demo.dbpedia-spotlight.org/), [OpenCalais](http://www.opencalais.com/), [LUIS](https://www.luis.ai/), [Stanford NER](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml)) do not support Ukrainian natively.

Do you know any NLP/NER tools allowing to work with the Ukrainian language?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is recent [lang-uk](https://dou.ua/lenta/columns/lang-uk/) initiative that resulted in [NER-model for MITIE](http://lang.org.ua/models/).

More in depth information about underlying corpus can be found at http://lang.org.ua/corpora/

Answer (score 3):

Stanza has NER model: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/available_models.html#available-ner-models

They use lang-uk too.